# Jagged line and markers when publish map on ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

We developed a native app with Esri iOS SDK and Esri Android SDK using ArcGIS Server, when we publish our map using Server, road lines become jagged. So when using this road service in our app development, app visual become so terrible.

How can we smooth the lines or disable jagged display of roads?

Not: You can see real image at this link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEPuw.png

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try different option (Fastest, fast, Normal, Best) for anti-aliasing parameter of map service properties.

- [Line aliasing in map services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sq00000028000000)
- [Setting map service properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000003p1000000)